# In js: how to get an object that includes all arguments of a function, including default params?

Tags: javascript

I recently learned of the ES6 feature that allows to define function params with a deconstructing object. Like so

```
function makeGenerator({type, max}) {
  //some code
  return something
}
```

I really liked this approach because it allowed me to see the arguments needed for a function, both where it is defined **and** where it is called. (Really good for self documenting code!)

I used it along with default arguments like so:

```
function makeGenerator({type = "natural", max = 10})
```

This works great!

But...

Sometimes I would like, usually for debugging purposes (but not limited to) get a summary of all the arguments of a function. However:

```
function makeGenerator({type = "natural", max = 10}) {
  console.log(arguments[0])
}

makeGenerator({type = "fibanacchi"});
```

will output:

```
{type: "fibanacchi"}
```

Even though, inside the function I am able to work with the variable max as expected, with its default value of 10, I would really like to have a summary of all the function's arguments, after they have been merged with the defaults.

Meaning, I would like some way for the example above to output:

```
{type: "fibanacchi", max: 10}
```

**Without** specifying each of the arguments separately in another place except for the function definition.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Couldn't you just log `arguments` instead of `arguments[0]`?

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager - No, that wont work. arguments[0] is the object, and it only shows one property, which is fibanacchi.

Comment: do you want to merge defaults with passed arguments, is that what you meant by ur question?

Comment: I thought that might be confusing as I re-read my question. this will actually print: `{ '0': { type: 'fibanacchi' } }`

Comment: @msoliman, yes. basically, I would like to know exactly what are the values of all the arguments the functions have to work with/expects, when it reaches its first line.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the stringed function and use a regex for taking the parameter part.

```js
function getArguments(fn) {
    var string = fn.toString(),
        count = 0,
        start = string.indexOf('('),
        i = start;

    while (i < string.length) {
        if (string[i] === '(') {
            count++;
        } else if (string[i] === ')' && !--count) {
            return string.slice(start + 1, i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return '';
}

function makeGenerator({ type = "natural", max = 10 }) {
    console.log(arguments[0])
}

function fn({ fo = 42, bar = (1 + (3)) * 4 }) { }

console.log(getArguments(makeGenerator));
console.log(getArguments(fn));
```

Comment: It doesn't do what the OP wants, and uses a frail means of getting the result anyway, yet 3 people vote for it. Ugh...

Comment: It actually does help the OP get what he wants :-). Just need to throw in a merge

Comment: @nina , is there a way to do this in a less "hacky" way (hacky is okay by me, but I will probably not use that method for anything more than debugging). is there something in the function object maybe that gets there? I don't really understand how this works

Comment: @TomKlino: A merge? With a string?

Comment: as I said in the above, it's hacky. but since it's already hacky, you can call `JSON.parse()` on it, and then merge it. hacky, not elegant, but works.

Comment: @TomKlino: `JSON.parse` won't help you here. Also it can fail with some default values. This is quite a bit beyond hacky, and again doesn't actually answer the question without some serious alteration, which is why I'm befuddled as to why it would get so many (or any) votes. But hey, if this is what you were after, then super.

Comment: actually no. the regex is a naïve one without checking of more parentheses inside. json does not work, because it is not a [JSON](http://json.org/) compliant.

Comment: well in the ideal situation I would like something native in js to just give me an object of what I defined in the function definition. But if there isn't one (yet, I hope), then using a hack that gets me closer is better than nothing. I agree that the answer does not correspond to the strictest standards of stackoverflow, but given that there isn't a better way, and something is better than nothing, this is not a bad answer and deserved its votes - IMO.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Your updated solution can still fail. You really shouldn't lead people into a sense of security for problems like this.

Comment: @TomKlino:. If you want it to actually work reliably, you'll need a full JS parser to analyze the string (of the whole function), so download Esprima. Then create a function that receives the function in question as well as the object with the actual data passed, converts the function to a string, builds an AST, analyzes the AST for the data you want, creates an object from that data and merges it into the object with the passed data.

Comment: ...or just use object properties instead of local variables, and you can have everything you want. In other words, adjust your solution to the language instead of trying to adjust the language to your desired solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the argument here for max, because none was passed. The feature you are using is working as designed, in that it *only* displays passed arguments.

In order to view the value of max, then you will need to explicitly name it when it is not passed as an argument.

Comment: I understand that `arguments` does not do it. I was hoping there would be some other object that refers to the object withing the brackets of the function definition.

Comment: @TomKlino It's not an object.